# How to get string response from backend application with angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm trying to get string response from my back application. i searched for this issue and almost in all the solutions they add { responseType: "text"} or {responseType: 'text' as 'json'} to get string, i added it but i can't arrive, here my angular code:

```
msg:any;
  func(){
    this.bookService.getRessource(url,{ responseType: "text"})
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.msg=data;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

This is my service, i have to add jwt to header:

```
getRessource(url,res){
   let headers=new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.authService.jwt});
    return this.http.get(url,{headers:headers});
  }
```

The funtion add a book to user's favorite list, it works and add it to database but the weird thing is the error message is shown in the console and i can find the string that i would like to get in that error. But i can't comprehend how the function works and then the error message is shown!!

This is the error message i receive:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/user/addBookToUser?username=admin&id=9", ok: false, …}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error you are specifically receiving and also what does the network tab for that request indicate about the response in terms of the content-type and what the payload looks like? Also `{responseType: 'text'}` would be added as an option to `this.http.get()` alongside `headers`. You aren't specifying `{responseType: 'text'}` in the actual HttpClient call currently.

Comment: can you please add the server code that treats the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current code, you are not placing `responseType: text` in the correct place. It needs to be an option of the actual HttpClient `get()` alongside `headers`:

```
msg:any;

func() {
  this.bookService.getRessource(url)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.msg = data;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}

getRessource(url) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.jwt });
  const options = { responseType: 'text', headers };
  return this.http.get(url, options);
}
```

Hopefully that helps!